# Best way to sort multidimensionnal array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimentionnal array like this example

```
$arr = array (
      range(9,4),
      range(8,0),
      range(2,7),
      range(-1,17)
   );
```

after showing its content I get this

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
2 3 4 5 6 7 
-1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Now the result I want to get is this

```
-1 0 0 1 1 2 
2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 6 6 
6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

I defined a function that sorts the array and returns the result I need, but I want to know if there is a simple way to do it using predefined functions or a simple and fast algorithm

this is my function

```
function sort_multi($arr)
{
   $length = 0;
   foreach ($arr as $value) 
     $length += count($value);

   $sorted = false;
   while(!$sorted)
   {
      $x = 0;
      $y = 0;
      $sorted = true;
      while(($x+$y)<($length-1) && isset($arr[$x][$y]))
      {
         $new_x = isset($arr[$x][$y+1])?$x:($x+1);
         $new_y = isset($arr[$x][$y+1])?($y+1):0;
         if(($new_x+$new_y)<$length && isset($arr[$new_x][$new_y]))
            if($arr[$x][$y] > $arr[$new_x][$new_y])
            {
               perm($arr[$x][$y], $arr[$new_x][$new_y]);
               $sorted=false;
            }
         $x = $new_x;
         $y = $new_y;
      }
   }

   return $arr;
}
```

the definition of `perm` is

```
function perm(&$a,&$b)
{
   $inter = $a;
   $a = $b;
   $b = $inter;
}
```

Comment: The result should be 2d array too or 1d array?

Comment: the first result is before sorting the array and the second is the result I want to get after sorting it ... my function does it correctly, I just need to know if there is a better way to do it

Comment: So should the result array be 2d (two-dimensional) or 1d?

Comment: two dimentions as shown in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which is the best way. But you can do it brute force: [**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vZRt20)

```
$arr = array (
    range(9,4),
    range(8,0),
    range(2,7),
    range(-1,17),
);

// simple checking of number of items per batch (since this is sort of like array_chunk, but jagged)
$chunks = array_map(function($batch){ return count($batch); }, $arr);
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr)) as $v) {
    $values[] = $v; // simple flattening
}
sort($values); // sort ascending (prepping)
foreach($chunks as $key => $batch) {
    // number of items in a batch
    // simple cutting (i can't find the function for this, i think there is)
    for($x = 0; $x < $batch; $x++) {
        $final[$key][] = $values[$x];
        unset($values[$x]);
    }
    $values = array_values($values); // reindex again (resetter)
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think array_walk_recursive could work well for something like this.

```
// Fill a temp array with all the values from the multidimensional array...
$temp = array();
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($item) use (&$temp) {
    $temp[] = $item;
});

sort($temp); // sort it...

// refill the multidimensional array with the sorted values.
array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$item) use (&$temp) {
    $item = array_shift($temp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Usually prefer a Bubble Sort, because at longest it will take the same as brute force.  Usually it is slightly more efficient though.